# vector sorting and changing data

Tags: c++, c, sorting, vector

I am struggling in doing this operation, I have a vector, its size might be `200000`, it contains data like `(156,256,789,1,2,1,1,1,63,89,7,8,45,1,1,2,5,8,9,6,47,8,96,5,465,6,etc)`.

My question is i like to get data as
`( 0,1,2,3,4,3,3,3,5,6,7,8,9,3,3,4,10,8,11,etc)`.

I need to do this operation in fast and effective way..Give some suggestion for the same.

> My code is

```
vector<int>* VectorReader::SortID(vector<int>* tempID)
{
std::vector<int>::iterator new_sortit;
vector<int> newit_ID;
newit_ID.resize(tempID->size());
copy( tempID->begin(), tempID->end(), newit_ID.begin());
int i = 0;
for( new_sortit =tempID->begin(); new_sortit != tempID->end(), i < tempID->size(); new_sortit++ )
{
    int min_ID = *min_element( tempID->begin(), tempID->end());
    int max_ID = *max_element( tempID->begin(), tempID->end());
    int search_NodeID =  std::find ( tempID->begin(), tempID->end(), min_ID) - tempID->begin();
    replace( newit_ID.begin()+search_NodeID, newit_ID.end(), min_ID, i );
    max_ID++;
    replace( tempID->begin(), tempID->end(), min_ID, max_ID );
    i++;
}
copy( newit_ID.begin(), newit_ID.end(), tempID->begin( ));
return tempID;
}
```

Comment: From the description I don't understand what the goal is. The example output you give isn't sorted... is sorting what you want, or something else?

Comment: I feel you just need one function which std::sort to replace your code. Or do I just totally misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is return a vector which corresponds to the input, but with each element replaced with a number which is the relative order in which that element occurred in the input.
That is, if we removed all duplicates from the input, the output for each element is the index of that element in the duplicate-free vector.

This might do the trick:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<int> Ints;
typedef std::map<int, size_t> IndexTable;

Ints findIndices(const Ints& input)
{
   size_t size = input.size();
   IndexTable indices;
   size_t index = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
   {
      if (indices.find(input[i]) == indices.end())
      {
         indices[input[i]] = index;
         ++index;
      }
   }
   Ints output(size);
   for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
   {
      output[i] = indices[input[i]];
   }
   return output;
}
```

Comment: @user2089677 Yes, one example. My guess at your intention was based on the example. If it's wrong, please clarify the relationship between input and output. This is (mostly) not the Psychic Network.

Comment: yes, it works well, some changes i need, i have given a example on what i need? my vector have element like vector1 =[56,78,2,4,1,56,9,11,56]. Is it possible to get the output as [5,6,1,2,0,5,3,4,5].

Comment: @user2089677 That doesn't look one bit like what you asked originally. You must have a better description of the problem for *arbitrary* input.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is to sort `tempID` in ascending order, I'd do like this:

```
vector<int> VectorReader::SortID(vector<int> tempID)
{
  std::sort(tempID.begin(), tempID.end());
  return tempID;
}
```